# I Found Error of Could Not Cast Value of Type when i load my json in Tableview

Tags: swift3, tableview, wordpress-rest-api

This is my code , could not append array type to UIImage , api is successfully loaded , i have problem in appending data

var images = UIImage

```
func downloadJsonWithURL() {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSObject {
            print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "guid"))

            if let actorArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "guid") as? [NSObject] {

                    if let actorDict = actorArray as? NSObject
                    {



                        if let name = actorDict.value(forKey: "rendered") {



                            **self.images.append(name as! UIImage)**

                            print("\(name)")



                        }

                    }

            }

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

this is my rest api

guid        {1}
rendered    :   http://thenewschef.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/startup.jpeg

Comment: A json object in Swift 3+ is **never** `NSObject`. You have to cast the objects to the proper Swift types (dictionary `[String:Any]`, array `[[String:Any]]`). And don't use `value(forKey` unless you know what KVC is and you  really need it. In Swift use key subscription (`jsonObj["guid"]`). The image of the *rest api* is funny but not really helpful. 

Comment: @sapna what is your `urlString`?

Comment: final let urlString = "...." @KetanOdedra

Comment: hide in comment my url

Comment: @sapna hide in comment my url?
what is your rest api[it will used in `urlString`] which you used to get data...

Comment: yes url string is my rest api url @KetanOdedra

Comment: Your rest api "http://thenewschef.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/startup.jpeg" is not api it is just image Url... you can check on postman..i already checked with `Alamofire`.

Comment: my rest api is guid{ } rendered : image path@KetanOdedra

Comment: @sapna how you pass your api in `urlString` can you show me your code & have you got response from api?
and what is BASE_URL of your rest api?

Comment: I got response from api.. as guid {} rendered:imagepath  .

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return images.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
      
        cell.imgView.image = images[indexPath.row]
        
}

Comment: final let urlString = "https://thenewschef.com/wp-json/wp/v2/..../"
var images = [UIImage]()

Comment: please view my code @KetanOdedra

Comment: @sapna is this your url https://thenewschef.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media

Comment: yes@KetanOdedra

Comment: but you have't mention this url...so i don't have any clue about your url...

Answer (score 0):

So, You Can Do This

```
var images = [[String:AnyObject]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    downloadJsonWithURL()
}

//Tableview methods

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 135
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DemoTableCell", for: indexPath) as! DemoTableCell

    let dict = images[indexPath.row]
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: dict["rendered"] as! String)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            cell.imgView?.image = image
        })
    }).resume()

    return cell
}


//your api call

func downloadJsonWithURL() {

   let urlString = "https://thenewschef.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    print(url as Any)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)  {
            print((jsonObj as AnyObject).value(forKey: "guid") as Any)

            let responseJSON = (jsonObj as AnyObject).value(forKey: "guid") as Any
            let json = (responseJSON as AnyObject) as? NSArray
            self.images = json as! [[String:AnyObject]]
             print(self.images)

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.demoTable.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

That's it you got your UIImage.

Comment: The cast-dance from `responseJSON` to `self.images` *`as Any as AnyObject as? NSArray as! [[String:AnyObject]]`* is hilarious.

Comment: @vadian There are so many ways for Casting but Temporary i Chose This.

Answer (score 0):

> Enhanced implementation of above solution using Higher order function to avoid all the cast dance.

Use the below code to fetch the response form Server & filter the required imageUrl's in a single array.

```
func downloadJsonWithURL() {
                 let urlString = "https://thenewschef.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media"
                 let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
                 URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {[weak self] (data, response, error) -> Void in
                 if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)  {
                 let guids = (jsonObj as? [[String: Any]])?.map { $0["guid"] }
                 let imagesArray = (guids as? [[String: Any]])?.map {$0["rendered"]} as? [String]

                 OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    //Reload Table here...
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```